# VS code JavaScript error syntax highlighter not working after upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have recently upgrade VS code. Now it's no longer showing the error highlights. Earlier, if I use any undefined function or variable, it used to underline it with red line.

i.e.. line number 5 on the image is not reflecting in red

[image]

Settings

```
 {
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "sonarlint.ls.javaHome": "C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Java\\\\jdk-12.0.1",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "update.mode": "start",
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
    "editor.autoClosingOvertype": "always",
    "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "always",
    "eslint.debug": true,
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
    "bracketPairColorizer.highlightActiveScope": true,
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": null,
    "typescript.tsserver.useSeparateSyntaxServer": false,
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "typescript.format.enable": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterCommaDelimiter": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterKeywordsInControlFlowStatements": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
    "debug.javascript.breakOnConditionalError": true,
    "debug.onTaskErrors": "showErrors",
    "zenMode.silentNotifications": false,
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript", "javascriptreact", "typescript", "typescriptreact"
    ]
}
```

Also have the these extensions installed

[image]

Comment: Do you have linting setup?

Comment: Please see the attached settings. I've updated the post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try configuring eslinter in React that should fix it. [Here](https://medium.com/@sgroff04/configure-eslint-prettier-and-flow-in-vs-code-for-react-development-c9d95db07213) is a good tutorial about how to do it